# git push and git clone works but not mvn release:branch

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I'm trying to build my Linux VM to interact with Git. I generated private/public SSH keys and put the public key in Git. I can `git clone` and `git push` without requiring a password. So I think everything is setup correctly.

But when I try to run `mvn release:branch` it's asking for a username and password.

Does it require that we need a different setup just for `mvn` commands?

Answer (score 0):

The [`mvn release` plugin](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html) would use the `project.scm.developerConnection` element in your `pom.xml` to know where to push a tagged source (or here a source with a new branch), before making the actual release to Nexus.

If that connection uses an https URL, then credentials would be required.

[This article](https://www.avisi.nl/blog/2015/04/07/improved-releasing-with-maven-and-git) shows that the connection might be specified explicitly:

> Apparently, the `release:branch` goal doesn't make any `release.properties` file or other files that the `release:perform` goal expects.

So try instead `mvn release:prepare`